# Django add data to manyToManyField on form submission

Tags: python, django

I would like to automatically add the User who submitted the form to the users many to many field on the below-given model when the form submits, how could I do this from the view?

The model:

```
class Project(MainAbstractModel):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25, default="Conflict")
```

The view:

```
def myconflicts(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        else:
            form = ProjectForm()
    return render(request, 'conflictmanagement/myconflicts.html')
```

And my form is simply:

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ["title"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the user in the view, for example with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import redirect

@login_required
def myconflicts(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            project = form.save()
            project.users.add(request.user)
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')
    else:
        form = ProjectForm()
    return render(request, 'conflictmanagement/myconflicts.html', {'form': form})
```

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
>   [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
>   to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
>   This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
>   browser.

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
>   [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).